# Code 1a Stamp ‘EEA Dependant’ ink stamp

Tags: schengen, united-kingdom

I applied for EEA Family Permit 3 times but I got refuse every time they give me very strange reason even I supplied all the documents they required it. I showed the refusal decision to many people and every one said that they not gonna give me EEA Family permit visa. I proved all the Regulations 2006 (6)(7)(12) etc, so I decided to use code 1a Stamp way to enter in the UK.

1. Can I go to UK on schengen Visa (traveling with EU/EEA Italian Wife)
2. Can I change my plan after getting schengen visa
3. After getting schengen visa can I book only one way ticket (because I want to move in UK after coming in France)
4. I am non EEA family member of an Italian National. I applied for schengen visa for long term. I have plan to move in UK after getting schengen visa. Here we have to report after coming back from schengen visit. if I get enter in UK so how can I report to Italian embassy that I am back as I will be in UK at that time planing to stay there.how to satisfied to Italian Embassy for that.

   5. is that any side effect to apply for future schengen visits.

Please advice me from  your past experience and future information.

Comment: Hi Gayot, I am sorry if you find it wrong my questions. and sorry for my stupid english. as I am not very good in english thats why got problem.

Comment: Heavens no! It's a wonderful question!  But this site is for travellers and we have no competence in people who want to MOVE to the UK.  I have asked the higher ups to 'migrate' your question over to the experts so you can get an answer real fast.

Comment: Also, you shouldn't edit out your previous refusals.  That will totally dilute the answers you get.  You want the best answer possible so be transparent about your circumstances!

Comment: Oh sorry, I just remove the previous refusals I thought it was look like an expats question as you told in your previous answer. that's why I delete it if you want I can put it again..

Comment: I have done the rollback for you.  Now please wait for the higher ups to come along, they will know what to do.

Comment: Nobody can judge your chances of success without knowing the reason for your family permit refusal.  The reason for refusing the family permit is also possibly a reason for refusing you entry when you present yourself at the border.   Can you edit your question to include the exact text if your most recent refusal?

Answer (score 1):

UK is not part of Schengen area so your schengen visa won't give you entry to UK.

As the spouse of an EU citizen you will be probably be able to reside in the UK as long as you are here with your spouse, who is exercising their treaty rights.

Note that there is some long term uncertainty with this as the UK is planning to hold a referendum on its EU membership.

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer.
Just want to be more clear. I am on schengen visa with my EU/EEA national wife. and on visit in france so now can I go UK through ferry with my wife using her treaty rights.

if yes can I buy only 1 way ticket when I get schengen visa thanks.